# acSelectionSetCrossing gives different result based on window zoom

Tags: c#, autocad

I am using autocad2007.I have some trouble while using the acSelectionSetCrossing option in selectionset it gives different result based on the window zoom.if i zoomed out the window then performing selectionset operation means it will work but if i zoom the window then perform selectionset operation means it gives less no. of result.

Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 0):

You didn't ask a question, so I'll guess. Graphical selection modes select entities based on their visible graphics, so you must ensure that whatever you want to select is visible.